# Lua: forward output from Minicom

Tags: lua, stdout

I have a Lua script and in there I open a **minicom** session which executes a script (with the **-S**" parameter).

```
local myFile = assert(io.popen('minicom -S myScript.sh ' myDevice ' -C myLogFile.log'))
local myFileOutput = myFile:read('*all')
myFile:close()
```

This works really fine.

But I would like to get the same output as if I execute the **minicom** command itself:

```
minicom -S myScript.sh ' myDevice ' -C myLogFile.log
```

Right now I don't get any output at all (I know that that's somehow obvious).

I would that the output should also occur at (at least nearly) the same time as with the **minicom** command itself. Not one big chuck of data at the end.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like

```
local myFile = assert(io.popen('minicom ...'))
for line in myFile:lines('l') do
  print(line)
end
myFile:close()
```

Comment: Great thanks! That's it! However, I use a version of Lua 5.2 and according to the newest book "In Lua 5.2 and before, all string options should be preceded by an asterisk. Lua 5.3 still accepts the asterisk for compatibility.". So I used `'*l'` instead of `'l'`